# How to match UTM squares between Excel and Shapefile?

Tags: qgis, excel, utm

I have an excel file with locations displayed in UTM 10kmx10km squares. I also have a shapefile with those same UTM squares and their coordinates, however I cannot seem to figure how to project the excel UTM squares.

I have tried to join both of the attribute tables but with no success. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: If you want to project data from the Excel file, you will have to add it via (_Layer_ > _Add Layer_ > _Add Delimited Text File_) from the toolbar. Note: the options might differ depending on the QGIS version (I am using 2.6).

Comment: please post a row of data from your spreadsheet. (to your original question.

Comment: This is what I have:
Canis lupus PE53